# STM32WL HAL_UARTEx_RxEventCallback not working

Tags: c, stm32, interrupt, uart, dma

I want to use stm32wl with sim800l. I couldn't get the uart buffer well but then I found a code about it. It is about UART DMA with IDLE Line Detection. Here is website [controllerstech.com](https://controllerstech.com/uart-dma-with-idle-line-detection/) . Never enter HAL_UARTEx_RxEventCallback. I couldn't find why.
I can see RxBuf changing with HAL_UARTEx_ReceiveToIdle_DMA but not entering the HAL_UARTEx_RxEventCallback.

Here is my codes and uart - dma setttings.

```
#define RxBuf_SIZE   60
#define MainBuf_SIZE 120

uint8_t RxBuf[RxBuf_SIZE];
uint8_t MainBuf[MainBuf_SIZE];

void HAL_UARTEx_RxEventCallback(UART_HandleTypeDef *huart, uint16_t Size)
{
    if (huart->Instance == USART1)
    {
        oldPos = newPos;  // Update the last position before copying new data
        /* If the data in large and it is about to exceed the buffer size, we have to route it to the start of the buffer
         * This is to maintain the circular buffer
         * The old data in the main buffer will be overlapped
         */
        if (oldPos+Size > MainBuf_SIZE)  // If the current position + new data size is greater than the main buffer
        {
            uint16_t datatocopy = MainBuf_SIZE-oldPos;  // find out how much space is left in the main buffer
            memcpy ((uint8_t *)MainBuf+oldPos, RxBuf, datatocopy);  // copy data in that remaining space

            oldPos = 0;  // point to the start of the buffer
            memcpy ((uint8_t *)MainBuf, (uint8_t *)RxBuf+datatocopy, (Size-datatocopy));  // copy the remaining data
            newPos = (Size-datatocopy);  // update the position
        }
        /* if the current position + new data size is less than the main buffer
         * we will simply copy the data into the buffer and update the position
         */
        else
        {
            memcpy ((uint8_t *)MainBuf+oldPos, RxBuf, Size);
            newPos = Size+oldPos;
        }
        /* start the DMA again */
        HAL_UARTEx_ReceiveToIdle_DMA(&huart1, (uint8_t *) RxBuf, RxBuf_SIZE);
        __HAL_DMA_DISABLE_IT(&hdma_usart1_rx, DMA_IT_HT);
    }
    /****************** PROCESS (Little) THE DATA HERE *********************/

    /* Let's say we want to check for the keyword "OK" within our incoming DATA */
    for (int i=0; i<Size; i++)
    {
        if ((RxBuf[i] == 'O') && (RxBuf[i+1] == 'K'))
        {
            isOK = 1;
        }
    }
}

/* USER CODE BEGIN 2 */

  HAL_Delay(2000);
  sprintf(cmd,"AT\r\n");
  HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart1,(uint8_t *)cmd,strlen(cmd),1000);
  HAL_Delay(1000);
  HAL_UARTEx_ReceiveToIdle_DMA(&huart1, RxBuf, RxBuf_SIZE);
  __HAL_DMA_DISABLE_IT(&hdma_usart1_rx, DMA_IT_HT);


  sprintf(cmd,"AT+SAPBR=3,1,Contype,GPRS\r\n");
  HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart1,(uint8_t *)cmd,strlen(cmd),1000);


  /* USER CODE END 2 */
```

```
static void MX_USART1_UART_Init(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN USART1_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE END USART1_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE BEGIN USART1_Init 1 */

  /* USER CODE END USART1_Init 1 */
  huart1.Instance = USART1;
  huart1.Init.BaudRate = 9600;
  huart1.Init.WordLength = UART_WORDLENGTH_8B;
  huart1.Init.StopBits = UART_STOPBITS_1;
  huart1.Init.Parity = UART_PARITY_NONE;
  huart1.Init.Mode = UART_MODE_TX_RX;
  huart1.Init.HwFlowCtl = UART_HWCONTROL_NONE;
  huart1.Init.OverSampling = UART_OVERSAMPLING_16;
  huart1.Init.OneBitSampling = UART_ONE_BIT_SAMPLE_DISABLE;
  huart1.Init.ClockPrescaler = UART_PRESCALER_DIV1;
  huart1.AdvancedInit.AdvFeatureInit = UART_ADVFEATURE_NO_INIT;
  if (HAL_UART_Init(&huart1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  if (HAL_UARTEx_SetTxFifoThreshold(&huart1, UART_TXFIFO_THRESHOLD_1_8) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  if (HAL_UARTEx_SetRxFifoThreshold(&huart1, UART_RXFIFO_THRESHOLD_1_8) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  if (HAL_UARTEx_DisableFifoMode(&huart1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /* USER CODE BEGIN USART1_Init 2 */

  /* USER CODE END USART1_Init 2 */

}
```

```
static void MX_DMA_Init(void)
{

  /* DMA controller clock enable */
  __HAL_RCC_DMAMUX1_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_DMA1_CLK_ENABLE();

  /* DMA interrupt init */
  /* DMA1_Channel1_IRQn interrupt configuration */
  HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(DMA1_Channel1_IRQn, 0, 0);
  HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(DMA1_Channel1_IRQn);

}
```

Comment: I didn't find any callback function calls in your code. I suspect your function is not called because you never call it?

Comment: @Ilya use this callback, HAL_UARTEx_RxEventCallback isn't this work after I call   HAL_UARTEx_ReceiveToIdle_DMA(&huart1, RxBuf, RxBuf_SIZE); ?

Comment: Your code does not contain any calls to that function. If you want to have a function executed, it has to be called **somewhere**, right?

Comment: @Ilya thank you sir, I always use arduino and I don't have good skill of C. I didn't think I need to call these once. HAL_UARTEx_ReceiveToIdle_DMA(&huart1, RxBuf, RxBuf_SIZE);
    __HAL_DMA_DISABLE_IT(&hdma_usart1_rx, DMA_IT_HT);